# File shared via AirDrop is incomplete

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I am working on an application one of the features of which is downloading and displaying PDF files. I had no problems implementing these features. Then I wanted to enable sharing of the files but ran into a strange problem.

Here's how my sharing code looks like:

```
log.debug("Will share file: '\(fileURL.absoluteString)'")
// an example of fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A6D5948-8F14-42FB-905A-D776BD975ED1/Library/Caches/d7e635bb-5baa-4fde-b60b-b3fb869cdf46/6.3%20Rambeskrivning%20Mark.pdf

let shareView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
dependencies.router.show(shareView, asPopoverFrom: barButtonItem)
```

Nothing fancy, but when I share the file via AirDrop, it is only 200-250 bytes on the receiving end and has a different name, something like "PDF document-373E47D68169-1.pdf" (instead of the original name).

My first thought was that the downloaded document is corrupted, but it is not (I checked both on a device and a simulator). If I choose another sharing option (for instance, "Save to Files"), the file is shared correctly. `UIDocumentInteractionController` exhibits the same behavior. I also thought this might be caused by not retaining the `UIActivityViewController` (`UIDocumentInteractionController` requires this for the AirDrop sharing to work), but letting the system do this seems sufficient.

The issue is reproduced on both iOS 12.1 and 11.4.1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact same issue where everything worked except AirDrop. Turns out my URL instance was relative which somehow caused a problem with AirDrop. I solved it by passing `activityItems: [fileURL.absoluteURL]`.